# Is there any non-monoid ring which has no maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, rngs

Is there any non-monoid ring which has no maximal ideal?

We know that every commutative ring has at least one maximal ideals -from Advanced Algebra 1 when we are study Modules that makes it as a very easy Theorem there.

We say a ring $R$ is monoid if it has an multiplicative identity element, that if we denote this element with $1_{R}$ we should have: $\forall r\in R;\: r.1_{R}=1_{R}.r=r$

Comment: Every _non-zero_ commutative ring has a maximal ideal. But what do you mean by a non-monoid ring?

Comment: @ZhenLin I add my meaning from monoid in the question.

Comment: I thought that this was simply "ring" or "unital ring", whereas a ring without such identity is "rng".

Comment: Sometimes people write rng for a ring with no identity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I heard "unital ring" for monoid ring before, it was good to mentioned, but the expressions "rng" is new for me, and for the other only "ring" it is used for monoid rings in notes that at the start of them, authors make agreement to call monoid rings simply "ring" because they don't want to observe non-monoids one in those notes.

Comment: I think maybe we can use the same argument as in monoid case, which is extending an ideal again and again, repeat many times, possibly uncountable times, until we get a maximal one. This proof requires Zorn's lemma and it also works on the non-monoid rings? I didn't see any difference made by the existence of identity.

Comment: @ChaoChen so you are saing that all rings should have a maximal ideal? Your words don't proof it because you didn't mention to anything that gauranties to earning maximal ideal when you were saing "extending an ideal again and again, repeat many times, possibly uncountable times, until we get a maximal one"!

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it very precise. Consider the set of all ideals, they form a partial order under the '$\subseteq$', and every chain of them is bounded (union of all ideals in a chain is also an ideal), so according to Zorn's lemma, there is maximal element among them, which is a maximal ideal. I didn't see 'identity' in this proof, but I am not sure if I missed something.

Comment: @Chao: But without an identity you cannot guarantee that an ideal is proper if and only if $1$ is not in the ideal. So the union of a chain of ideals might not be a *proper* ideal.

Comment: I got it! Sorry I definitely missed something, thank you!

Comment: FYI, when I hear the term "monoid ring", I think of the concept related to "group ring" i.e. the ring $\mathbb{Z}[M]$ consisting of formal sums of monoid elements with the product is given by the monoid operation. e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{N}] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]$. (the isomorphism sends a formal natural number $[n]$ to the monomial $x^n$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $D$ is a valuation domain with unique maximal ideal $M$, then there are some conditions where $M$ is an example of a commutative rng with no maximal ideals.

As I remember it, one can choose a domain with a value group within $\Bbb{R}$ such that the group has no least positive element. Then, one can argue that the maximal ideal of that valuation domain $\{r\mid \nu(r)>0 \textrm{ or } r=0\}$ is a rng without maximal ideals.

Scanning the web, I think [this pdf](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/NoMaxIdeals.pdf) contains an argument of that sort.

Comment: @rshwieb , thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Not every non-unital ring (or rng) has a maximal ideal. For example take $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ with trivial multiplication, i.e. $xy=0$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$, then a maximal ideal is nothing more than a maximal subgroup. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234995/mathbbq-has-no-maximal-subgroup) why such a group does not exist.

Comment: Your answer was nice, and as I can choose only one answer, so I selected for rshwieb , because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field with characteristic zero that is mentioned in the pdf he brought below page 2, so his answer cover your answer too. But your thought was nice too.