# Proving that "Every non-trivial ring (i.e. with more than one element ) with unity has a maximal ideal" implies axiom of choice is true

Tags: ring-theory, axiom-of-choice, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know that assuming axiom of choice or equivalently Zorn's lemma , it can be proved that every non-trivial ring with unity has a maximal ideal (two sided ) . The wiki article on axiom of choice says that this statement regarding existence of maximal ideal in any non-trivial ring with unity is equivalent to axiom of choice , but I am not able to prove this converse implication . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you expect to be able to prove everything that is mentioned in Wikipedia? Some proof are difficult, and require more than a handful of preliminary theorems under your belt.

Comment: [This has come up before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774245/krulls-theorem-and-ac).

Comment: See [W. Hodges: Krull implies Zorn](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-19/2/285.full.pdf+html)

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Can you at least  please give a reference  ?

Comment: @martini : I don't have access ...

Comment: I gave three references in my answer, I think that the last one should be accessible without a paywall.

Answer (score 5):

The proof is not trivial to come by.

Originally given by Hodges, the proof shows a variant of Zorn's lemma can be proved from the assertion that every commutative ring with a unit has a maximal ideal.

> *Wilfrid Hodges*, [**Krull implies Zorn**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-19.2.285), *J. London Math. Soc. (2)* **19** (1979), no. 2, 285--287.

Some decades later, Banaschewski gave a somewhat different proof of that same fact.

> *Bernhard Banaschewski*, [**A new proof that “Krull implies Zorn”**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.19940400405), *Math. Logic Quart.* **40** (1994), no. 4, 478--480.

Both paper are not long, and quite readable granted that you're comfortable with reading choice-related papers.

> *Marcel Erné*, [**A primrose path from Krull to Zorn**](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/118738), *Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin.* **36** (1995), no. 1, 123–-126.

Is also related to this proof, although I haven't really read that one.

Comment: No . the "A New Proof ..." paper also is not open access ..

Comment: I said "the last one", and I posted three. You're talking about the second. :-)

Comment: yeah right :-) . But , is there any open access link to the second?

Comment: I don't know. I use a paywall from my university.

Comment: I'll add that of the three, I definitely prefer the original paper by Hodges. I find it the easiest to digest.

Comment: @Asaf: And now we know: $\text{some}=1.5$, at least when counting decades.

Comment: @Brian:  The quantifier runs over the real numbers! ;-)