# Zorn's lemma and maximal ideals

Tags: logic, commutative-algebra

Let's consider two statements: Zorn's lemma and theorem about existence of maximal ideals in commutative ring with $1$.

It's easy to prove that Zorn's lemma implies existence of maximal ideals.

I wonder if the converse proposition is true, i. e., does existence of maximal ideals implies Zorn's lemma? My approach was to construct a ring structure on an ordered set which satisfies Zorn's lemma condition such that existence of maximal ideal implies existence of maximal element in the set, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the existence of maximal ideals (in non-trivial rings with unit) implies Zorn's Lemma. A reference is:

Marcel Erné, *A primerose path from Krull to Zorn*, [pdf-link](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/118738/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_36-1995-1_15.pdf)

Comment: [Looks familiar](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/317038/622).

Comment: Indeed. I couldn't find it quickly via the search function.

Comment: Yeah, it took me more than a few minutes.