# Commutative unitary ring without maximal ideal without axiom of choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to find a semi-constructive example of a unitary commutative ring without any maximal ideals assuming that axiom of choice is incorrect and/or a model of $\sf ZF$ where we have such a concrete ring.

This question is similar to the questions [Vector space bases without axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461436/vector-space-bases-without-axiom-of-choice) and [A confusion about Axiom of Choice and existence of maximal ideals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317028/a-confusion-about-axiom-of-choice-and-existence-of-maximal-ideals).

What I tried is to use $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space without a basis and try to construct some chains of ideals on a related ring and try to show that a maximal ideal corresponds to a basis but didn't achieve much.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, existence of maximal ideals in rings is properly weaker than choice.

Comment: @egreg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317028/a-confusion-about-axiom-of-choice-and-existence-of-maximal-ideals - they seem equal

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @egreg: Sit down, prime ideals are weaker than choice as they are equivalent to BPI.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/317038/622

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was looking to read that but thought maybe there is an easier construction, especially using $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, or a possibility for a more general answer.

Comment: Well. You can either construct special models with particular examples, and that normally involves techniques like forcing and stuff; or you can sort of repeat the proof that the existence of maximal ideals implies choice and start with a set that cannot be well-ordered as a counterexample. This set can be $\Bbb R$ in models where there is no Hamel basis, for example.

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182014/proving-specific-unital-rings-have-maximal-ideals-without-zorns-lemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field, let $I\subset k^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the ideal of sequences that are eventually zero, and let $S=k^{\mathbb{N}}/I$.  Then maximal ideals in $S$ are in bijection with nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$.  In particular, in any model of ZF in which there are no nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, there will be no maximal ideals in $S$.