# Questions related to maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In my previous sessional exams, I was asked to prove these two:

> 1) Find a ring which doesn't have a maximal Ideal.
>
> 2) If a ring has unity, then it has a maximal Ideal.

About the first one we can think about the trivial ring where there are only two additive subgroups *(one the group itself and the other containing the identity element only....)*. Is there some other case for the first one...

About the second one I don't know how to show it...

Kindly help...

Comment: example for 1 : $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where p is prime operations addition modulo p and multiplication modulo p.

2 seems to be wrong as every field is a ring with unity and does not have a maximal ideal.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi but how....

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Your example doesn't work, since it has multiplicative unity.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi: Every field **does** have a maximal ideal, namely $(0)$.

Comment: @curious: My bad, I was confused. I thought $(0)$ and $F$ cannot be maximal.

Comment: @Swapnil Tripathi: Please recall the definitions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ideal

Comment: Yes, I read it. :) Thanks

Comment: @patang: Your remarks about the trivial ring are not correct.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg but what's wrong in it..

Comment: @patang: The trivial ring is $\{0\}$. But probably you mean a ring with zero multiplication? Every abelian group can be considered as a ring with zero multiplication. But when it has only the two canonical subgroups, this does not mean that there is no maximal ideal. In fact, $0$ will be the maximal ideal.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I understood ,this doubt is clear to me ..thanks..

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg in your previous comment how is $0$ a maximal ideal....,I think there's no maximal ideal in that case because $0$ is not proper ideal and maximal ideal should be proper Ideal...

Comment: @patang: the thing you think about as “the trivial ring” is likely **F** ₂, also known as ℤ₂, ℤ/2ℤ, or GF(2). The true trivial ring has only *one additive subgroup* (itself), also trivial as a group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The simplest example is the zero ring. It has no maximal ideal (recall that maximal ideals are required to be proper ideals). For a more interesting example, consider the ring $(\mathbb{Q},+,0)$, where $+$ is the usual addition and $0$ is the zero multiplication. It is known that $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ has no maximal subgroups, which implies that $(\mathbb{Q},+,0)$ has no maximal ideals.

2) is not correct. As I've said, the zero ring (and this is unital with $0=1$) has no maximal ideal. But if $R$ is a non-zero unital ring, then $R$ has a maximal ideal. In fact, one may apply Zorn's Lemma to the partial order of proper ideals of $R$. The crucial observation is that for any chain $\mathcal{K}$ of proper ideals, their union $\bigcup \mathcal{K}$ is again a *proper* ideal. And this uses the existence of a unit and that an ideal is proper iff it does not contain the unit.

Comment: $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ has no maximal subgroups ,if I'm asked to prove it in my exam,how shall I prove it....

Comment: You shall think about it at least a couple of minutes ... If you do not want to do this, check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234995/

Comment: by zero multiplication you possibly mean multiplying any two elements in the ring gives zero...

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{...}$

Comment: I accpted the answer because 1.) is perfect...about 2.) I don't know about what is zorn's lemma so,can't understnd it..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma

Comment: Well, I have seen a definition of a unity in a ring as a non-zero element, which means that the zero ring is then a ring without unity. I know this is strange, but it is exactly for the reason that zero ring is too weird to be a unit ring.

Comment: The zero ring is a unital ring, and this is not weird, it is absolutely natural. If you want unital rings to be $\neq 0$, you will have to make case distinctions in many constructions of rings, which is absurd. I know that, unfortunately, there are still books and lectures in which $1 \neq 0$ is a general assumption. In order to understand some concept, one really also has to understand the so-called pathological cases. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/sexy-vacuity