# Is it true to say that : Every submodule of a module M contains in a maximal submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring with $1\neq 0$ and $_RM$ a left $R$-module. Is it true to say that : Every proper submodule  of a module $M$ is contained in a maximal submodule?

Comment: “Every nonzero module has a maximal submodule” is quite strong a property for the ring. See [this article by Hamsher for the commutative case](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-06/S0002-9939-1967-0217059-8/S0002-9939-1967-0217059-8.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Not all modules have maximal submodules at all, much less maximal submodules that contain any given submodule.

As an example, the (left) $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Q$ does not have maximal submodles.

Comment: Could you prove that $\Bbb Q$ does not have maximal submodules?

Comment: @KennyLau It's done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234995/mathbbq-has-no-maximal-subgroups), for instance. That post is using the term "group", but that's the same as $\Bbb Z$-module for our intents and purposes.