# Does maximal ideal exist in a commutative ring without identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Does maximal ideal exist in a commutative ring without identity?

I was reading this proof https://equatorialmaths.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/existence-of-maximal-ideals/ where they use Zorn's lemma on the partially ordered set of proper ideals, and here we need identity to prove that the union of a chain is a proper ideal. What will happen otherwise? I didn't get a similar question in stack if it is a duplicate one let me know. Thanks

Comment: As the duplicate says, "no not in general", and of course that doesn't mean a nonunital ring *can't* have maximal ideals.   Another thing is that the ordinary definition for maximal ideals in rings with identity may not always be useful for rings without identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any abelian group $G$ can be made into a trivial commutative ring without identity by taking $x \times y = 0$ for all $x,y$, and then ideals are exactly subgroups of $G$. This then comes down to the fact that some abelian groups do not have maximal subgroups, for example ($\mathbb{Q},+,0)$ (see [$(\mathbb{Q},+)$ has no maximal subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234995/mathbbq-has-no-maximal-subgroups))

Comment: So you want to say maximal ideals don't exist for such a ring where the group has no maximal subgroup?